# "A [...] of riches" — what word is missing?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, nouns

There is a phrase that goes "a X of riches" which suggests that one had so much to choose from, lots of good choices. What is the missing word?

Comment: Have you Googled [*a of riches*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=a+of+riches)? It gives you the answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is also the phrase, "an embarrassment of riches"

Comment: I think you've been [beaten to the punch](http://imgur.com/5YZhw)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the comment.

Answer (score 3):

... not to forget, a plethora of riches.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the expression *a wealth of riches* to mean an abundance of choices or appealing options, such as found in these examples:

> ...*in the region of Tuscany, a region with **a wealth of riches** for
>   the keen cyclist, culture vultures and fun seekers*. ([1](http://www.gustocycling.com/why-use-gusto.html))

---

> *The music is bold and epic, which are attributes you'll pick up on immediately.  There is a sense of might behind many of the tracks as
>   the rich orchestral sound plays to great scope and the choir fills the
>   speakers with startling beauty. Thankfully,*
>   Excelsius *is far from being one dimensional; it offers **a wealth of
>   riches** that will appeal to anyone who enjoyes a great film score.* ([2](http://scorenotes.com/soundtracks/excelsius.html))

---

> *Explore Minsk, Belarus's modern city, built as a memorial to the glory of Soviet communism or step beyond the capital and find **a
>   wealth of riches** that remain largely unknown to the outside world:
>   the natural splendour of primeval forests, rivers and lakes; flora and
>   fauna in abundance; stunning museums empty of visitors; rich culture
>   and tradition; historical sites dating back to the Middle Ages;
>   beautiful churches...* ([3](http://books.google.com/books/about/Belarus.html?id=AHHpbnUNiW4C))

---

> **Team Canada: A wealth of riches**
>   *Mike Babcock's greatest blessing as head coach of Canada's 2010 men's hockey team is also his greatest curse: Being positively spoiled for
>   choice.  For head coach Babcock, executive director Steve Yzerman and
>   the rest of the brain trust, the quandary is choosing the 23 that
>   blend the best.*
>
> *There's plenty of choice. Smyth or Staal? Green or Bouwmeester? Fleury or Ward? Either way, any way, it seems they can't go wrong.* ([4](http://www.theguardian.pe.ca/Sports/Hockey/2009-08-29/article-1283701/Team-Canada%3a-A-wealth-of-riches/1))

If the number of choices seems almost too great – enough to cause the fortunate one to perhaps blush – there's also the idiom *[embarrassment of riches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassment_of_riches).*

Comment: Isn't being rich already wealthy?

Comment: @Mitch: I suppose - I didn't make up the expression.  Besides, _wealth_ can refer to things other than money: _a wealth of talent_, _a wealth of data_, etc., so the phrase _a wealth of riches_ isn't necessarily redundant.

Comment: @Mitch "wealth" in this case means "a large amount", not "a large amount of money".

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of people using "a world of riches" and that was the first that sprung to mind. A google search delivers some wide ranging usage (search with the quotes).